# How to draw the flags of various countries in LaTeX

Tags: packages, diagrams, languages

[image]

English:

For example say I like Korea!

can you make it?

**Korean:**

**예를 들어 나는 한국이 좋다!**

**당신은 그것을 만들 수 있습니까?**

Answer (score 7):

Package `worldflags` is there for you :) See at https://www.ctan.org/pkg/worldflags

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{worldflags}


\begin{document}

Here is Korea's flag:\par\medskip

\worldflag{KR}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it turned out to be like that!

Answer (score 2):

There is another possibility using `twemojis` package. Being very small the flags I have added
`scalerel` package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{twemojis}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\begin{document}
This is the flag of the South Korea

\scaleobj{10}{\twemoji{flag: South Korea}}
\end{document}
```

[image]